# Run into error: no module named 'encoding' when I launch Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I launch the `Jupyter notebook` from anaconda navigator, there will be some errors.  I am using Mac.
I tried to search it up on Google and StackOverflow, but I still can not figure a way to fix this issue.
Based on my searches, I assumed the issue is showing up because I have multiple python versions, and there might be some issues with my directory? ( Maybe in Anaconda, it is pointing to a wrong python directory? )

and these are the screenshots of the error.
Can someone see what is the issue here?

**Screenshots of the errors** :

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 1):

Use :
`pip install torch-encoding`

if it throw any error try to clone it from

`https://github.com/zhanghang1989/PyTorch-Encoding`

after that,  run the setup

`python setup.py install`

Comment: I believe the issue for me is having a wrong python path.